# Why does jQuery return null for the height of the div?

Tags: jquery, height

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function getDocumentHeight()
  {
     // What's the page height?
     var height = $('#mainbody').height();
     alert(height);
   ...
 getDocumentHeight();  }
```

jQuery keeps alerting `null` for the height of my `#mainbody` div. I don't get why, it should at least be `500px` or so.

Comment: You sure <div id="mainbody"> exists?

Comment: You don't have `id="#mainbody"`, with the `#` in it do you?

Comment: @Nick: +1 for psychic debugging.

Comment: @Tomalak +1 for the phrase "psychic debugging"

Comment: @Marko - +1 for phrase praise

Comment: +1 for all of you and minus 1 for me, it works now. not even an idea what went wrong, suddenly working. maybe an old script got cached. sry for that one!

Comment: This happens to me on iOS, don't know why, ..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the content is being loaded dynmically, the elements may not have a height yet. Try moving this code to the bottom of the page, directly above  and see if that resolves.

UPDATE:
Try placing your code in

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var height = $('#mainbody').height();
  alert(height);
});
```

outside of your

```
$(document).ready();
```

Comment: I have this problem, but my code executes after the DOM is ready. Wierd.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a template for your markup for example with angular or ember use the script tag and call the script from the template.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With 100ms delay works well for me. Without delay not working.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var imgWidth = $('#id').width();
    var imgHeight = $('#id').height();
    console.log(imgWidth);
    console.log(imgHeight);
}, 100);
```