# Size of element does not update after append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was working on the following code like so:

```
console.log("size before: " + list.size());
list.append($(newItem));
console.log("size after: " + list.size());
```

Output in console is:

```
size before: 1
size after: 1
size before: 1
size after: 1
size before: 1
size after: 1
```

HTML:

```
             <ul class="form-list" id="list">
                <li>
                  <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only">Items</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control date-picker input-lg" id="sprint-start"></input>
                        <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus list-add"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove list-remove"></i></a>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </li>
              </ul>
```

I'm trying to do index based operations in other functions, and can't make it work because the element size and indexes do not update. Can I do anything about this?

I've looked at solutions that require `load` ([jQuery returns null for element height? why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680811/jquery-returns-null-for-element-height-why)) but I don't think it will work considering other events are using the index (at which point, it has already loaded).

Comment: Can you show us what `list` is?

Comment: Is newItem a valid child of list or only some text?

Comment: Your list is a cached jQuery object, it doesn't update itself.

Comment: I added the HTML to the question. @undefined Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `list` is a cached jQuery object, it doesn't update itself. You should either manipulate the collection yourself (*by using the `add` method if you want to add an element to the collection*) or create a new collection.

Also note that you are appending elements, jQuery doesn't add the appended elements to the current set and if `list` refers to the `ul#list` element, `size` returns count of the selected elements in the set not their children's. You are probably looking for the `children` method:

```
console.log("size before: " + list.children().length);
list.append($(newItem));
console.log("size after: " + list.children().length);
```